# Display Wordpress enqueue style css files in inline?

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

Hi everybody I have this Wordpress website that I want to transform into an AMP website, one of the challnging task is to rewrite the css in inline.

So in the wordpress framework we have this functions.php file and inside we have the [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) function.

```
/**
* Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
*/
function wpdocs_mytheme_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/style.css' );}

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_mytheme_styles' );
```

Basically Wordpress will give us this line on out front end pages

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style'  href='Path_to/css/stle.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

**Can I change this display mechanism to make Wordpress display the registered styles in **INLINE** this way :**

```
<style amp-custom>
<!-- The content of the style.css -->
<!-- .... -->

</style>
```

Yeah basically i have a lot of these files and I don't want to make a static change by opening each one and copy/pasting content n the header any idea?

Comment: Which AMP plugin you are using?

Comment: Hi Sami Ahmed , I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/ with transitional mode, so I have my classic website and the one finishing with ?amp for amp version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
<style amp-custom>
  {% include "/assets/css/main.min.css" %}
 </style>
```

OR,

```
<style amp-custom>
      /* any custom styles go here. */
      body {
        background-color: white;
      }
      amp-img {
        border: 5px solid black;
      }
      amp-img.grey-placeholder {
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
```

**Reference** : [AMP-DEV](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages/?referrer=ampproject.org)

Comment: Yeah and I found a function wp_add_inline_style which could be interesting to look up

Comment: yeah you could also used that (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/)

Comment: Hi @ Krishna Savani yeah I managed to do some auto inlining but I hit the wall since there's a max size for the css that you can inline in AMP so I am trying to do some custom CSS just for the AMP pages right now Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the styles directly to the page head using wp_head()

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_styles', 100);
function my_custom_styles()
{
 echo "<style>*{color: red}</style>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason why you want to make use of inline styling?

Comment: Hi yeah I want to make it AMP website which require inline styling https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/converting/